# trying to use "," delimiter in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to use the `textscan` function. Here is the data I am trying to read:

```
"0", "6/23/2015 12:21:59 PM", "93.161", "95.911","94.515","95.917", "-5511.105","94.324","-1415.849","2.376","2.479"
"1", "6/23/2015 12:22:02 PM", "97.514", "96.068","94.727","96.138","-12500.000","94.540","-8094.912","2.386","2.479"
```

The data logger I am using puts quotes around all values even though they are numbers. If they were separated by commas I could just use `csvread`. You can see some of my commented out failed attempts. Here is the code I have been trying:

```
fileID = fopen('test3.txt');

%C = textscan(fileID,'"%f%s%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f"', 'delimiter', '","');
C = textscan(fileID,'"%f","%s","%f","%f","%f","%f","%f","%f","%f","%f","%f"');
%C = textscan(fileID,'%s', 'delimiter', '"');
%C = strread(fileID, "%s %s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", ",");
fclose(fileID);
celldisp(C)
```

If i run line 3 I get:

```
C{1} = 
NaN 
NaN 
94.324 
NaN 
... omitted lines here ...
NaN
99.546
NaN
```

If I run lines 4, 5, or 6, I get:

```
warning: strread: unable to parse text or file with given format string
warning: called from
    strread at line 688 column 7
    textscan at line 318 column 8
    test2 at line 4 column 3
error: some elements undefined in return list
error: called from
    textscan at line 318 column 8
    test2 at line 4 column 3
```

Comment: Is it not working? Are you getting an error? Please describe the problem you get when running your code.

Comment: Please rather edit your question to add these details

Answer (score 0):

You want the magic word. The magic word is not please here, it's `multipledelimsasone`.

Basically, you want both `"` and `,` to be treated as delimiter characters. `textscan` looks for any of the delimiter characters, not a given order, which is why '","' didn't do what you expected. Turning `multipledelimsasone` on makes `textscan` treat any combination of `"` and `,` as a single delimiter.

```
C = textscan(fileID,'%f%s%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f', 'delimiter', '," ','multipledelimsasone',1);
```

Without this option on, what `textscan` thinks is happening is lots of empty values; the delimiter list isn't taken as any sort of order, just a list of possible separators.  So if it sees `","`, it thinks you have three delimiters with nothing inbetween → two empty values → `NaN`.

Comment: Thank you @nkjt I think this is the right path but it is still not outputting correctly I tried changing a few things but still no luck. Im looking into the 'multipledelimsasone' syntax now.

Comment: Ok no luck with nkjt's line. I'm sure there is something simple I am missing but I haven't been able to find it. Is there any other suggestions